# Deleting the "\r" or carriage return from a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am using CloudMailin to receive emails and then send the plain text to my Ruby on Rails app. To access the body of the email in plain text I use params[:plain].

If I were to just print the relevant part of the plain text it would look like this:

```
Style 130690 113
Price $335.00
Stock # 2882524
```

I have used regex to name capture certain pieces of data:

```
style, price, stock = params[:plain].scan(/^(?:Style |Price \$|Stock \# )(.+)/).flatten
```

This works however each variable has a "\r" or carriage return at the end. So, if stock is 80201943, it would appear in my database as "80201943\r".

I then try to update my database with this code:

```
shoe = Shoe.where(:size => "7").first
shoe.update_column(:stockId, stock)
```

Then when I check my database the :stockId has a "\r" at the end of it.

I have tried doing

```
stock.chomp("\r")

stock.chomp

stock.strip

stock.gsub("\r", ""),
```

None of these remove the "\r" from the string. How can I remove it?

Comment: Both `.strip` and `.chomp` work for me on 2.3.6 to remove a trailing `'\r"` - can you give a bit more info in your example?

Comment: `stock.chomp("\r")` and `stock.chomp` both should work. What they return in your case? Have you tried `stock.gsub("\r", "")`?

Comment: What version of Ruby, and OS are you using?

Comment: I just tried stock.gsub("\r", ""), and it still did not work.

Comment: I am on Ruby 2.6.0 and Mac OS 10.14

Comment: I will update the post to include more information

Comment: Just guesswork but it might be that you try to use `stock.chomp` expecting to alter the variable itself when in fact it will just return a new one with the trailing `\r` removed. Try using `stock.chomp!` which will change the variable in place.

Comment: It feels like you didn't assign this value to your variable.

Comment: Try `shoe.update_column(:stockId, stock.chomp)`

Comment: The problem was I was not actually altering the variable. Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: @ulferts: `chomp!` will *not* alter the variable in place. It will alter the object that is referenced by the variable, which is a completely different thing. A thing and the name of the thing are not the same thing. Please, don't spread mis-information this way. The "only way" (modulo reflection, i.e. `Binding#local_variable_set`) to alter a variable is by assigning to it, in particular, *no method* (other than `Binding#local_variable_set`) can alter a local variable, ever.

Answer (score 0):

I was not altering the variable, I was just returning a new one. To alter the variable I needed to use:

```
stock.chomp!
```

Comment: This does *not* alter the variable. This alters the object that is referenced by the variable, which is a completely different thing.